# Render not worked in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I new in react and need show each new message, but in the render func is need in set index in  render_mess for show message from array. Is it possible to display all the elements of without loop?

```
class New extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {new_mes: [], mes_for_show: []};
    }

    new_message = () => {
        //some code
        var render = this.state.mes_for_show
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.new_mess.length; i++) {
           render.push(<div key={i}>{new_mess[i]}</div>)
           this.setState({mes_for_show: render});
        }
     }

     render () {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.mes_for_show}</div>
        ) 
     }
```

How can I get all the elements in the render, at once or what needs to be fixed?

Comment: You are missing closing braces for `new_message` as well as the class.

Comment: Just keep the data in the state, don't put JSX in it (`this.setState({mes_for_show: render});`). You could [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your `this.state.mes_for_show` array in the render method and return some JSX for each element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments your code is not a React way of doing things. Try to think a little bit simpler and read more about state and how we render components or elements. I assume that `new_mes` will be an array of strings, here is a very simple React code does the same job.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { new_mes: [ "foo", "bar" ] };
  }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>{
          this.state.new_mes.map( (mes,i) => (
            <div key={i}>{mes}</div>
          ))
        }</div>
      )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As you can see you don't need another state property to hold the JXS for rendering. You can do this in your render method easily. Also, we use `.map` instead of `for` loops here. Because `.map` returns an array and we can easily use this array to render our elements.

I don't suggest using indexes as keys, if possible use some unique values or generate those unique values if there is not present.

**Update after comments**

Here is an example how you change the values with a function.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { new_mes: ["foo", "bar"] };
  }

  new_mes = () => this.state.new_mes.map( (mes,i) => (
    <div key={i}>{`Hello ${mes}.`}</div>
  ))

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{
        this.new_mes()
      }</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here, we use a separate function to create our new messages mapping through our state. We use this function in the render method, by invoking it.

If you really use your state to hold the new messages, here is how you can do this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { new_mes: ["foo", "bar"], mes_for_show: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.new_mes();
  }

  new_mes = () => {
    const mes_for_show = this.state.new_mes.map((mes, i) =>
      <div key={i}>{`Hello ${mes}.`}</div>);
    this.setState({ mes_for_show });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.mes_for_show}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In this example we use an external function again. But, instead of returning an array including our elements, we are assigning this array to a variable (same with our state name), then using `this.setState` we are updating our state. The big difference is here we use `componentDidMount` life cycle to invoke our function. Then we use our new state in our render method.

We do not invoke our function in our render method since it sets our state. This causes a loop in our app. Since we set our state in render method, component rerenders then again sets state then again rerenders...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but func new message is required, since need create array with previous messages and add new message

Comment: You are welcome. So you will change the messages somehow? Actually you can do this in the `.map` but using a function is also possible and most of the time people prefer this method. How do you change the messages for example?

Comment: At the moment I do not plan, but in the future it is possible

Answer (score 0):

you generaly can render an array of components in react 16, something like this

```
return [
  <li key="1">One</li>,
  <li key="2">Two</li>,
  <li key="3">Three</li>
];
```

but you have bigger issues, beside `new_message` never being called in that function your for loop is not executing because when you evaluate it it looks like this `for (var i = 0; i < 0; i++)`, so you never populate `mes_for_show`. also don't set state on every iteration of the loop, store new components in an array and when loop is done set new state.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/252943/) is a fiddle you can play with.